# Use jaxb:class and annox:annotate together in jaxb2-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin, annox

When I use `jxb:class` with `annox:annotate`, I get this exception:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/usr/workspace/project/package/file.xjb; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 35; the compiler failed to honor this customization annox: annotate. He was attached to an incorrect location or is inconsistent with other binds.
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:310)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:363)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
```

I used this configuration:

```
<jxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MyType']//xs:element[@name='property']">
    <jxb:class ref="org.project.model.MyType" />
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Please add your complete bindings file with all XML namespace declarations.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I might have been wrong about my interpretation. I'll still leave the answer until we've got it cleared.

---

Author of [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) and [annox](/questions/tagged/annox) here.

It is quite obvious that it won't work.

This:

```
<jxb:class ref="org.project.model.MyType" />
```

Instructs JAXB to use a presumably existing class `org.project.model.MyType` *instead* of generating a new on. So there's no class generated, so [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) has nothing to add annotations to.

I hope it is clear, why you can't add annotations to the already existing classes. :) That would be too much to ask. You can only add annotations to the generated classes.

Comment: I want to add annotations at the field, not at the class. That's my problem.  

`code <jxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MyType']//xs:element[@name='property']">
   <jxb:class ref="org.project.model.MyType" />
   <annox:annotate>
    <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.validation.constraints.Null" />
   </annox:annotate>
  </jxb:bindings> `

Comment: @IsmaelG. Does `jaxb:class` works without `annox:annotate`? Here? And try to write two separate bindings for `jaxb:class` and for `annox:annotate`.

Comment: Yes, `jaxb:class` works without `annox:annotate`. But when I write two separate bindings for each one, I get the same exception as I mentioned before.

Comment: @IsmaelG. Ok, this might be a bug. Please file an issue here https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/issues send me PR a minimal reproducing project here: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/tree/master/tests

Comment: I have an example of the problem here:  

https://github.com/mundodojava/jaxb2-maven-plugin

Comment: @IsmaelG. I'll take a look but give me time.